# WP_SIGNON in wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am trying to implement login system by using Facebook API. I am able to take all required data from the API. Then for login I am using wordpress function. In wordpress I am getting all the data (I have tasted the data by using print_r()). But login is not happening. I am using the below mentioned code.

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = "himanshu_kumar04@yahoo.com";
$creds['user_password'] = "123456";
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
do_action('wp_login', $user);
wp_set_current_user($id);
wp_set_auth_cookie($id, true);
$redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
exit;
```

Comment: Here if I am printing the value of $user i am getting the value

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine just I did one mistake that I have entered duplicated data in my database so my code gets confused that which username to take.